# How to have two angular apps in the same source code, but deploy as two separate apps?

Tags: angular

I would like to have two separate angular 'apps' in my source code, but share the same styling (in my case, stored in the assets folder).  These apps can have entirely separate app.modules (and everything else), but need to share the same content in the assets folder (where I keep my styling).  How would I do this?  I thought it might have something to do with multiple package.json files or angular.json, but I have no idea.

Comment: https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/

Comment: Your angular.json has a projects part. You can simply provide several projects here

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm That's super helpful, but how do I build multiple applications from the package.json file?

Comment: @kroe761 ng build <appname>

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Nx` for this, it's going to make your life way simpler for organizing and deploying your projects. I'm not sure how it works with respect to sharing `assets` folders, but I do know it can manage multiple projects, libraries, and is highly configurable.

https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/what-is-nx

Note: I have 0 stake in this project, I'm just a user.